# Read_excel in Pandas

Tags: pandas, converters

Using pandas 0.19.2.

My goal is to read an excel file and keep everything as string, no conversions.

My excel file that contains the following:

`Row1    Row 2
52.60   52.80
68.7k   67.5k
0.80%   0.80%`

I tried reading the excel file using the following commands

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:\Dash\static\Calendar-01-01-2017.xls')
df = pd.read_excel('C:\Dash\static\Calendar-01-01-2017.xls', converters={'Row1':str,'Row2':str}))
df = pd.read_excel('C:\Dash\static\Calendar-01-01-2017.xls', converters={0:str,1:str}))
```

Unfortunately I end up with this:

`Row1    Row 2
52.6    52.8
68.7k   67.5k
0.008   0.008`

In the end, I would like to pass it to a list:

```
df = df.values.tolist()
```

but I end up with long values such as

0.0080000000000001

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Please edit your question in a way that will show the content of your excel and your desired output, so we can help you. But I can already tell you that the three separate commands starting with df will just overwrite each other, so the first two aren't doing anything useful for the final success.

Comment: If the file isn't big, or if you don't have very many, you can always read from clipboard and set the dtype to str.

Comment: Also, don't worry about long values. It is probably just fp error.

Comment: Thank you Marjan,
As mentioned in my post, my desired output is to keep everything as it is in the excel - meaning 52.60 to stay 52.60 instead of 52.6.
or 0.80% to stay that and not convert into 0.008.
Demetri, not sure what fp is but I do not want the long value, I'd like it to stay 0.80% and not 0.0080000000000001.